# Cut and paste from one Google worksheet to another using a script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with lots of data in one worksheet. In order to reduce clutter, I have written a function that will look for rows with dates older than the current date, copy them to a worksheet name Backup and delete the entry from the current worksheet.

My fxn is shown below. When I call it, it copies about half of the data. I have to run it several times, before it empties my worksheet. And when it does it does not write the last value into the target worksheet.

I would appreciate any pointers to improve my function.

```
function movePros() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var TZ = CalendarApp.openByName(ss.getSheetByName("Templates").getRange("E1").getValue()).getTimeZone();
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), TZ, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Put your events here");
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, dataSheet.getMaxRows(), dataSheet.getMaxColumns());
var count = 0;

// Create one JavaScript object per row of data.
objects = getRowsData(dataSheet, dataRange);
var res = objects.length;

for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
 var rowData = objects[i];
 var tmp = Utilities.formatDate(rowData.endDate, TZ, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

 var last_row = targetSheet.getLastRow();
 targetSheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);
 var target_range = targetSheet.getRange("A"+(last_row+1)+":H"+(last_row+1));

 //Browser.msgBox("The length is " + rowData.eventId.length );

 if ((tmp.valueOf() < date.valueOf() ) && (tmp.valueOf().length > 3)){       
      //Browser.msgBox(rowData.eventId);
      var source_range = dataSheet.getRange("A"+(i+2)+":H"+(i+2));
      source_range.copyTo(target_range);
      count++;
      dataSheet.deleteRow(i+2);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
 }     
 }  
 ss.toast(count + " rows copied", "Feedback", 5);
 }
```

Comment: Do you need to use the `copyTo()` method for a specific reason (eg to copy formats)? If not, my general comment would be to try and avoid calling Spreadsheet services (gets, copyTos, flushes etc) inside a loop. My plan of attack would be 1. feed source data into Javascript array 2. loop through that array and build a new array by pushing splices from the source array based on your condition 3. write the new array to the archive sheet with one setValues call 4. clear the source sheet and rewrite the (reduced) original array back there with one setValues call. Does that make sense?

Comment: If your data is sorted by date.. just find the first row that is older than today and then copy over rest of the rows in one swoop rather than row by row. This is along the note that AdamL is making as well.

Comment: I want to thank everyone. Special thanks go to AdamL and Arun. I took your advice and made it work

Comment: Great! Please post your answer and mark it as accepted to this will be useful to the next person ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function movePros() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var TZ = CalendarApp.openByName(ss.getSheetByName("Templates").getRange("E1").getValue()).getTimeZone();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), TZ, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Put your events here");
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
  var count = 0;
  var orig_last_row = targetSheet.getLastRow(); //we use this as our reference

  //dataSheet.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
  var header_data = dataSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, dataSheet.getMaxColumns()).getValues();
  var data = dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, dataSheet.getMaxRows(), dataSheet.getMaxColumns()).getValues();
  var srcArray = new Array();
  var dstArray = new Array();
  var headerArray = new Array();

  //get the header into our array, this line contains our column headers
  var buff = header_data[0];
  headerArray.push(buff);

  for (i in data){
    var row = data[i];

    try {
      var tmp = Utilities.formatDate(row[5], TZ, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

      if(tmp.valueOf() < date.valueOf()){
        srcArray.push(row);
        count++;
      }else{
        dstArray.push(row);
      }

    } 
    catch(err){
      //Logger.log("reached the end of the array");
    }

  }

  dataSheet.clearContents();

  if(srcArray.length > 0){
      targetSheet.getRange(orig_last_row+1, 1, srcArray.length, srcArray[0].length).setValues(srcArray);
  }  

  if(dstArray.length > 0){
    dataSheet.getRange(1, 1, headerArray.length, headerArray[0].length).setValues(headerArray);
    dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, dstArray.length, dstArray[0].length).setValues(dstArray);
  }


  ss.toast(count + " rows copied", "Feedback", 5);
}
```